# Scroll offset above 20px with href=#whereiwantscroll in html or css

Tags: javascript, html, css

Look at the problem :[Screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/N6ART.png)

I added a sticky div with auto scroll button using:
`<a class="petite-police-tel" href="#BISHOKUS">BISHOKUS</a>`

And in the div called BISHOKUS:
`<div id="BISHOKUS"...`

But i added a sticky so it's not aligned with the top of the div.

So , my question is : **How to shift a few pixels ?** Like that :[Screenshot 2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZOZJ0.png) if it's on JS please help me to insert it on the code cause I don't know much about it

---

Look at my code in the sticky :

`<div class="sticky">`

`<li style="padding: 5px; margin: 10px; display: inline-block; cursor: pointer;">`

`<a class="petite-police-tel" href="#BISHOKUS" style="margin-top: 20px;">BISHOKUS</a>`

`</li>`

Look at my code in the div :

`<div id="BISHOKUS" class="cases-progr" style="position: static;background-color: #202225; padding: 25px; margin-top: 20px; margin-bottom: 10px; border-radius: 1.25rem;">`

`<h1 style="margin-top: center;">Commandes Bishokus</h1>`

`</div>`

Comment: add `margintop` on the `div` & the `number` would be the `height` of the `sticky` element

Comment: you should add your code in a snippet so we can help you debug the problem. its hard to understand like this

Comment: Please provide a [mcve].

Answer (score 0):

On the `id="BISHOKUS"` div, give it following css:

```css
/* The offset value should be the height of the sticky div */
margin-top: -50px;
padding-top: 50px;
```

TL;DR
What happens is, we move the whole div up by 50px with the negative margin and then move the divs content down again by 50px with a positive padding. This makes the scrolling stop at the divs start position but the content is offset by 50px so effectively we've made a scroll offset.

Note that the div is now 50px taller than originally, so other styling may render it weird, for example if it has a background-color, it will look wrong, so you would need to work around that.

**Edit:** In your case I believe a new `div` is easier to solve your problem.
Create a new wrapper `div` around the BISHOKUS-div and move the `id` to that, and style it properly.

(Also I've used an offset of `50px`, since I don't think `20px` is enough, but you be the judge of that, just remember to change both `margin` and `padding` values to the same value):

```html
// Move the id property up to the wrapper div
<div id="BISHOKUS" style="margin-top: -50px;padding-top: 50px">
  <div class="cases-progr" style="position: static;background-color: #202225; padding: 25px; margin-top: 20px; margin-bottom: 10px; border-radius: 1.25rem;">
    <h1 style="margin-top: center;">Commandes Bishokus</h1>
  </div>
</div>
```

The reason why I want you to create a new div is because you are using margin already and to set the margins correctly (with only one div) you would have to calculate a new `margin-top` (which isn't hard to do: `20px` + `50px` = `70px`), but using the wrapper div instead, makes it more reusable, if you need more links than just one)

Comment: Hi , I try it but it does'nt work :(

Comment: Then you need to show some code.

Comment: Look at my code in the sticky :

<div class="sticky">

<li style="padding: 5px; margin: 10px; display: inline-block; cursor: pointer;">

<a class="petite-police-tel" href="#BISHOKUS" style="margin-top: 20px;">BISHOKUS</a>

</li>

Look at my code in the div :

<div id="BISHOKUS" class="cases-progr" style="position: static;background-color: #202225; padding: 25px; margin-top: 20px; margin-bottom: 10px; border-radius: 1.25rem;">

<h1 style="margin-top: center;">Commandes Bishokus</h1>

</div>

Comment: Pasting the same code as in your original post isn't helpful, had hoped that you would at least paste the tried code that failed. Anyways, I updated my post with something new you can try.